# How would I get the number of bans a person has done?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm looking for a way to get the number of bans a moderator has done, here is what I have so far. I'm guessing I have to loop thru each ban?

```js
let targetMod = message.mentions.users.first()

message.guild.bans.fetch().then((bans) => {

bans.forEach((ban) => {
//My problem is here, I dont know how to check who did the ban
})

})
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what the object "bans" looks like?

Comment: @deterjan it's a collection of [`GuildBan`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildBan)s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moderator is not actually provided in the info. You will need to check the audit logs for this (will only go back to a certain time, it's not fully accurate)

```js
let logs = await message.guild.fetchAuditLogs()
logs = logs.entries.filter(e => e.action === "MEMBER_BAN_ADD")
logs = logs.entries.filter(e => e.executor?.id === targetMod.id)
console.log(logs.size) //should be the rough amount of bans
```